# a matching phrase or idiom, to the arabic equivalent 'compelled me to the argument'

Tags: idiom-requests

If two people were discussing something and they want you to share your thoughts, even more judge. A bit like a lawyer. If someone started with saying something that the other person thinks is unimportant and trivial perhaps because it may play against him. But you say 'no harm in listening to what he has to say, plus, he has forced me to hear him'

Is there a phrase, that is used to mean that 'has forced me to hear him'.
In arabic we say ' ألزمني الحجة', which literally means 'compelled me to the argument'. But I don't think it's suitable. 
Any phrases or idioms that are kind of matching in English, maybe even a law terminology or a common saying?

Comment: There's *force to the table* (which might allude to a figurative *negotiating* table), but I can't think offhand of anything similar that simply forces you to *discuss* something regardless of whether you have a prior position and/or a vested interest in the outcome of the discussion.

Comment: English does have various expressions along the lines of "He prevailed upon/persuaded/convinced me to hear him out," which suggests not so much entering into negotiations on some issue as listening to the other person's pitch or argument or side of the story.

Comment: There's *captive audience.*  It means you have no choice but to listen.  But you would not really say "...plus, I am a captive audience."  Just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the OP correctly, perhaps getting "**caught up**" or "**caught in the middle**" are suitable phrases.

> [**caught up**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=caught%20up%20(in)) *idiom*: to find oneself involved in something; unwittingly, he had got *caught up* in a corruption scandal inside the company he was working for. (WordReference.com)
>
> [**caught in the middle**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/caught+in+the+middle) *idiom*:
> Also, ***caught in the cross-fire***. Between two opposing sides, as in “the writers are often caught in the middle between editor and publisher, who are political opponents,” or “when parents don't get along, the children are often caught in the cross-fire.” Long used in military situations, these terms began to be used figuratively in the second half of the 1800s. The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary (The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**Let's Hear Him Out**

[Definition of Hear Me Out from Urban Dictionary:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hear%20me%20out)

> A request that the listener/audience waits until they have heard all
>   the information before voicing their opinion. Often said when the
>   speaker anticipates that what they are about to say will be
>   prematurely interrupted, dismissed or ignored without allowing the
>   full story being told.

I'm not sure that I completely understand the idiom, but I think this is close.  It expresses an obligation to let someone express themselves completely, and to consider everything that they have to say, even if what they say isn't obviously relevant or particularly compelling.

Answer (score 0):

'no harm in listening to what he has to say, plus, he has a compelling argument'

The above is a common idiom.